# Center list inside of a div

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I know there are a lot of other answers out there, but I don't know if Im just doing something wrong, but they aren't working.

Basically, I have a "logo" (it's just my name) in a div("name") on the left hand side of a container div("header"). I also have my navbar links on the right of the name div, which are in the "nav" div.

The issue is that the nav div is actually floating to the top of the header div, while the name div is perfectly centered. A picture: 
[image]

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=“en”>
<head>
  <title>Toby Caulk</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
  <header>
      <div id="name">
          <h1>Toby Caulk</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="nav">
          <nav>
              <ul>
                  <li>Home</li>
                  <li>Resume</li>
                  <li>Portfolio</li>
                  <li>Contact</li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      </div>
  </header>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
*{
  font-family: monospace;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
}

#name {
 float: left;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

#nav {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
  font-weight: 150;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

What I want is for the nav div to be centered vertically inside of the header div, just like the name div is doing. How do I do this?

Comment: By centered I assume that you mean vertically?

Comment: @j08691 Correct, I'll edit my question to make that more visible.

Comment: `#name` is defining the height of the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments and the properties I added to `#name`

```css
*{
  font-family: monospace;
}




#header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
}

#name {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block; /* Ensures that #name and #name aligns side by side */
  line-height: 100%; /* Makes to ensure vertical centering */
  vertical-align: middle; /* Makes sure it's centered vertically */
}

#nav {
display: inline-block;
}



nav li {
  font-weight: 150;
  font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block; /* You can align them without using float */
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <header>
      <div id="name">
          <h1>Toby Caulk</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="nav">
          <nav>
              <ul>
                  <li>Home</li>
                  <li>Resume</li>
                  <li>Portfolio</li>
                  <li>Contact</li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      </div>
  </header>
</div>
```